# How to navigate to an image from within c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I was wondering how you, on WP8, can navigate to / open an image?

Suppose I just saved an image to my Save Pictures folder, I now want to navigate the user to that image so they can share it on facebook.

Lets say I have:

```
MediaLibrary lib = new MediaLibary();

Picture p = library.SavePicture("foo.jpg", imgStream);
```

How can I navigate to p as if the user had clicked it from the picture library?

Answer (score 0):

A simple method for navigate into image is related to [Efficient image manipulation in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921557/efficient-image-manipulation-in-c-sharp). I think that you need an framework for precessing like [AForge.NET](http://code.google.com/p/aforge/).

Comment: I don't think that Is what I need. I just want the phone to navigate to a picture. thanks

Comment: @Toadums You must processes this image first. If you want to use for phone try a light library for Hogh algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You could always try passing the url of the image as a string to a page that has nothing on it except an "Image".  Then as soon as you navigate to the page you open up the image from the url(url can be for an isolatedstorage file) and set it as the "Image" on the page.